# How to start appium server from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, appium, appium-ios, jenkins-cli, python-appium

I have a problem for starting appium server from Jenkins. If I go to the configuration and type 'appium' in shell execution, appium command is not found.

> [appium-mobile-test] $ /bin/bash -xe /var/folders/cm/mx5dgfln7k31q46xccnxsl4h0000gp/T/hudson6637451669921729894.sh
>   + appium
>   /var/folders/cm/mx5dgfln7k31q46xccnxsl4h0000gp/T/hudson6637451669921729894.sh: line 2: appium: command not found
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

I'm using Mac Mini and if appium server will be started from terminal, it's working fine.

Does anybody have a similar issue or know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
Change the path in execute shell using

export PATH=~/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:

Check the appium installation and start it from there. For me appium is installed in this location.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js &

Comment: thank for answering. i'm using jenkins slave to connect my mac min to jenkins. there are several ways to run the slave. If i run it from browser, appium command wouldn't be found. But if i run itu from terminal, appium command will be found.